# Construct a function $f :X\to \mathbb R$ strictly positive and $\mu$-integrable on $X$.

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $(X,\mathcal B,\mu)$ a measure space such that : $\mu(X)=+\infty.$

1. We assume that there is a function $f:X\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ strictly positive and $\mu-$integrable on $X$. For all $n\geq 1$, we pose : $A_n= \left \{ x\in X, |f(x)| \geq \dfrac{1}{n} \right\}$. Show that  $\forall n \geq 1 \; A_n \in \mathcal B$  and $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite.
2. We assume that there exists a sequence $(A_n)_n \subset \mathcal B$ s.t : $ X =\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$ and $0 <\mu(A_n) <+\infty $ for all $n\geq 1$.
   Construct a function $f :X\to \mathbb R$ strictly positive and $\mu$-integrable on $X$.

**My attempt :**

1. Let $n\geq 1$, $A_n = f^{-1}([\frac{1}{n},+\infty[,$ or $f$ is measurable so $A_n \in \mathcal B$.

$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \subset X$ for the other inclusion let $x\in X$, $f$ is strictly positive so $ \exists \varepsilon >0$  :$|f(x)| \geq \varepsilon$, so for $n= [\frac{1}{\varepsilon}]+1$, $x\in A_n.$
By using Markov inequality, we have $\mu(A_n) \leqslant n\int fd\mu <+\infty$, so $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite.

2. I get stuck here !

Is my first answer is right? and how to construct $f$ ??
Thank you in advance !

Comment: For 2., consider $B_n = A_n \setminus B_{n-1}$ to have disjoint events instead, and write $f(x)=\sum_n I\{x\in B_n\} w_n$ for some well chosen weights $w_n$.

Comment: First, thinks you for your help ! 

Let $B_n \subset \mathcal B$ a sequence s.t : $B_0=A_0$, and $B_n=A_n \setminus B_{n-1}$ for all $n\geqslant1.$ We have $ 0 < \mu(B_n)\leqslant \mu(A_n) <\infty,$ so we pose $\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \chi_{B_n}(x)w_n$ s.t : $w_n=\dfrac{1}{n^2\mu(B_n)}$ for all $x\in X$. 

$f$ is strictly positive and $\displaystyle \int fd\mu= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mu(B_n)w_n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}<+\infty.$ 
what do you think?

Comment: My advice was incorrect. I don't think you actually need to consider $B_n$. Writing $f(x) = \sum_n \chi_{A_n}(x) w_n$ for well chosen positive weights should work.

Comment: Thank you ! me too i was wondering why we need to use disjoint sets !
So for $w_n=\dfrac{1}{n^2\mu(A_n)}$, 
$f$ is strictly positive and $\displaystyle \int fd\mu= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mu(A_n)w_n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}<+\infty.$